# The best way to creating like system using PHP and MySQLi

Tags: content-management-system

Hi I've some users and some posts and what I'm looking for is the best way to let users like a post , keep their username and show the number of posts' like.

I've a table and in that table each row is for one post ...

My idea is writing usernames that like a post in one column and number of likes in another column but I don't know if it's the right way or not.

Comment: Please make sure your question is [on-topic for this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Comment: My actual question is : Is writing all users that like a post in a single column correct or not

Comment: That won't prevent an user from liking the same post twice or even more. You should make a new table (e.g. likes) and save all the given likes in there.

Comment: Hmm each like in separated row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose both your tables for users and posts have "id" columns (so we also assume that you have at least two tables, "users" and "posts"). From what I understand, you would like to write all usernames that liked a post in the "posts" table, and also have a counter to keep track of how many users have liked the post. It's pretty straightforward that you introduce some redundancy here. And let's not talk of what happens if an user is deleted (hint: a big mess).

The idea is to create a new table "likes" where you will enter the id of the user who liked a post, which will be referenced by its id. So this table basically needs two columns : "userid" and "postid". You could add a third for the timestamp if you want, adding extra info on the likes.

It may complicate some request a bit (to retrieve the names of the users who liked a post), but with good table relations, some boring consistency checks could be achieved without having to perform any query (example : a deleted user should not be present in this table, a post that not longer exists cannot be liked). And you can do this with foreign keys.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm searching for. <3 Thanks!

Comment: There are probably quite a lot of new concepts here (queries using JOIN (retrieve usernames from post), consistency, keys and foreign keys) but trust me, if you learn how to properly use these, that's really worth it. Especially keys and foreign keys, way under-rated by way too many developers in my opinion.